# Bad Image error when trying to run cygwin on windows 10

Tags: c++, c, cygwin

I recently installed cygwin together with clion on my laptop. It worked fine for a few hours, suddenly the IDE could not build the project, and then when I tried to run cygwin terminal, I got the message:

> Bad image :C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1,dll is either not designed to run
>   on Windows or it contains an error...

I tried to look it up and I realized it is something to do with a bad update which was installed automatically. I didn't find any information about cygwin in this context and i don't know how to find the update that caused this.
in anyone here familiar with the problem?

Comment: It sounds like a virus. The best antivirus I know, is not using Windows at all. But perhaps that's not an option for you.

Comment: shutdown windows and restart. If the problem persists reinstall the cygwin package.

Comment: thank you for your comments. perhaps i forgat to mention that i allready reinstall it. the problem just occured again